# What's the difference between Android Beam vs S Beam?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, samsung-galaxy-s-3, nfc, android-beam

What is the difference between Android Beam on the Galaxy Nexus and S Beam on Galaxy S3?

Are these two features inter-compatible? Can I transfer data between the two devices?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even though Android Beam and S Beam serve similar purposes, they actually work very differently and are **not** compatible with one another.

Android Beam uses NFC to pair your devices over Bluetooth, then transfers files over the Bluetooth connection. I believe it can also transfer very small pieces of data (contacts, links, etc) directly over NFC, as the [Ice Cream Sandwich version highlights page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html) implies:

> For larger payloads, developers can even use Android Beam to initiate
>   a connection and transfer the data over Bluetooth, without the need
>   for user-visible pairing.

S Beam, however, [uses Wi-Fi Direct to perform data transfers](http://www.androidcentral.com/hands-s-beam-samsung-galaxy-s-iii) instead of Bluetooth. Their reasoning for doing this is that Wi-Fi Direct offers faster transfer speeds (they quote up to 300 Mbps). Therefore, this will only work with other S Beam enabled devices, currently limiting it to communication between two Galaxy S3s.

However, the SGS3 *also* supports Android Beam, so you can use that to transfer something between a GNex and an SGS3. [Here is a tutorial on Sprint's website](http://support.sprint.com/support/tutorial/Use_Android_Beam_Samsung_Galaxy_S_III_16GB/40803-1445-2) (should be essentially the same for other versions of the SGS3).

Comment: Apart from the difference in data transfer method (Bluetooth vs. Wi-Fi Direct), Android Beam in Jelly Beam and S Beam are also different in how they use NFC. S Beam uses the  ICS Android Beam to do its work, while the new Jelly Bean Android Beam feature is not visible to an ICS device (it uses a different LLCP port). It will be interesting to see how this will be solved when (if?) the SGS3 is updated to Jelly Bean.